# X11 Xterm Keyboard layout is off by one or worse.

Tags: x11, aix, xterm, x11-forwarding

I am running Xming on my local machine which is a windows box.  I am connecting to Xming from an AIX box.  I am connecting as root, because I need to perform a software installation with X11 windows.  I am able to pull up xterm for example, and a X11 window pops up with Xterm, but the keyboard is all jacked up.  Everything seems to be off by one or worse, and lots of other keys just flat out dont work such as the enter key.  The xterm application isnt important, but every X11 window I open has this problem.

For example: A single press and release of the key:

```
--- row 1 ---
q = q
w = q
e = w
r = e
...
[ = p
] = [
\ = \
Enter = ]

--- row 2 ---
a = nothing
s = a
d = s
...
: = l
' = ;

--- row 3 ---
z = z
x = nothing
c = z
v = x
b = c
n = v
m = b
< = n
> = m
/ = ,

--- misc ---
space = space
tab = tab
` = '
1-9 = 1-9 (these are the only ones that are correct)
anything on the numpad = some variation of ^[[F (numpad 1 for example)
ctrl = \
alt = nothing
backspace = nothing
del = ^[[3~
esc = `
```

Here is the output of my setxkbmap -print

```
bash.root@myServer:/ # setxkbmap -print
Couldn't interpret _XKB_RULES_NAMES property
Use defaults: rules - 'xorg' model - 'pc101' layout - 'us'
xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes  { include "xfree86+aliases(qwerty)"       };
        xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
        xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us" };
        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc101)"     };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message

```
Couldn't interpret _XKB_RULES_NAMES property
```

tells you what the problem is: [`setxkbmap`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/setxkbmap.1.html) cannot find the configuration your X server is expecting, so it falls back (to a value which does not work for you).  Xming's website has a [trouble-shooting](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/trouble.php) page which may help.